# How do I draw text using OpenGL, SDL and C++?

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

I heard about SDL_TFF which I read about [here](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article1953.asp) but I don't understand how am I supposed to connect the TrueType2 library.

Maybe there is something better out there?

Comment: Here's a good answer if you decide to use ttf: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289447/using-sdl-ttf-with-opengl

Comment: Fourteen years have passed, yet no one answered the question?

Comment: @SorooshNoorzad There are 4 deleted answers. One of them is "not an answer", i.e. it says to use another library (Qt). The other 3 are correct, but they are link-only. So they have only put a link to the resource what they use. I think the link-only answers could be summarized and that would be an useful answer. **If someone would do that, I would happily share the content of the here deleted answers with him.**