# Rendering text in openGL 4 - does not work

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I've been trying to render text using glutBitmapCharacter().

This is what I've got so far as a 2D text rendering function:

```
void drawString(int x, int y, char* string) {
int i, len;

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glRasterPos2i(x, y);

for (i = 0, len = strlen(string); i < len; i++) {
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18, (int)string[i]);
}
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
}
```

In the scene rendering function, I make this call:

```
drawString(0, 0, "TESTING");
```

These are the only x and y values in which any text will be displayed, in which case "TESTING" appears in the middle of the screen with "TE" in red (the colour I want) and "STING" in black.

All the code for dealing with this function that I've seen has been using earlier versions of openGL and deprecated code, so I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 5):

The above is definitely not openGL 4 compliant code.

Refer to [the OpenGL 4 Reference manual](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/) and you will seethat *glColor*, *glRasterPos* don't even exist there (they are deprecated .. I believe even back in openGL 3)

In order to learn how to use openGL with the modern way that is not using the fixed functionality I would recommend [this tutorial](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/)

So basically the answer is that without *glRasterPos* I believe that this function can't work
in openGL 4. (or 3 for that matter)

For a feasible method refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262951/what-is-state-of-the-art-for-text-rendering-in-opengl-as-of-version-4-1)

Comment: Forward-only vs compatibility is a runtime per-context option, and won't prevent code from compiling.

Comment: Yes you are right Ben, did not mean to say compile. Thanks for the heads-up

Comment: If his problem was using *removed* features (deprecation and removal are *two different things*), then his code wouldn't display any text at all. But that's not what he's seeing. He's able to get text to display, but it's broken. Also, it's hard to create a 4.0 core context by accident; in all cases, it requires special-case code.

Comment: Nicol you do have a point. So maybe the OP actually does not have a 4.0 core context but is working with the default context in which case his question should be stated in a different manner

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I'll see what I can do with FTGL tomorrow.