# How to draw bitmap fonts in OpenGL 3.1+?

Tags: opengl

I'd like to have some text in my OpenGL application. However, I'm using 3.1+, and all articles  I found on the Internet use deprecated features, like display lists or glBitmap or (the worst case) GLUT.

What should I use on Win32 then? (except pre-written text in pre-made textures, of course)

Comment: Have you seen [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262951/what-is-state-of-the-art-for-text-rendering-in-opengl-as-of-version-4-1)? Maybe it might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Freetype](http://www.freetype.org/) is a software font engine that supports SFNT-based bitmap fonts.