# Using SDL_ttf with OpenGL

Tags: opengl, sdl, sdl-ttf

I'm using OpenGL and SDL to create a window in my program.

How do I use SDL_ttf with an OpenGL window?

For example I want to load a font and render some text. I want to draw the text using an SDL OpenGL surface.

Answer (score 34):

Here's how to do it:

1. Initialize SDL and SDL_ttf, and create a window using `SDL_SetVideoMode()`. Make sure you pass the `SDL_OPENGL` flag.
2. Initialize your OpenGL scene (`glViewport()`, `glMatrixMode()` etc.).
3. Render your text with SDL_ttf using e.g. `TTF_RenderUTF8_Blended()`. The render functions return an SDL_surface, which you have to convert into an OpenGL texture by passing a pointer to the data (`surface->pixels`) to OpenGL as well as the format of the data. Like this:

```cpp
colors = surface->format->BytesPerPixel;
if (colors == 4) {   // alpha
    if (surface->format->Rmask == 0x000000ff)
        texture_format = GL_RGBA;
    else
        texture_format = GL_BGRA;
} else {             // no alpha
    if (surface->format->Rmask == 0x000000ff)
        texture_format = GL_RGB;
    else
        texture_format = GL_BGR;
}

glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture); 
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, colors, surface->w, surface->h, 0,
                    texture_format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surface->pixels);
```

4. Then you can use the texture in OpenGL using `glBindTexture()` etc. Make sure to call `SDL_GL_SwapBuffers()` when you're done with drawing.

Comment: I did exactly as you said and I can't get it to work. It gives me a white rectangle instead of text.

Comment: Hi @DonaldDuck, I guess you got the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750624/text-in-opengl-using-sdl-ttf

Comment: I was using TTF_RenderText() and getting crazy pixels.  Blend mode GL_RGBA worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Based off of: http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/SDL_ttf:Tutorials:Fonts_in_OpenGL

The code below is an example of how you can render the text on top of finished 3D model you may have built.

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL_ttf.h"

/.../

void RenderText(std::string message, SDL_Color color, int x, int y, int size) {
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glPushMatrix();
  glLoadIdentity();

  gluOrtho2D(0, m_Width, 0, m_Height); // m_Width and m_Height is the resolution of window
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glPushMatrix();
  glLoadIdentity();

  glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glEnable(GL_BLEND);
  glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

  GLuint texture;
  glGenTextures(1, &texture);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

  TTF_Font * font = TTF_OpenFont("pathToFont.ttf", size);
  SDL_Surface * sFont = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, message, color);

  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, sFont->w, sFont->h, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, sFont->pixels);

  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  {
    glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex2f(x, y);
    glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex2f(x + sFont->w, y);
    glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex2f(x + sFont->w, y + sFont->h);
    glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex2f(x, y + sFont->h);
  }
  glEnd();

  glDisable(GL_BLEND);
  glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glPopMatrix();
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glPopMatrix();

  glDeleteTextures(1, &texture);
  TTF_CloseFont(font);
  SDL_FreeSurface(sFont);
}

/.../

int main() {

/.../ Render 3D stuff here

  // Prints out "Hello World" at location (5,10) at font size 12!
  SDL_Color color = {255, 0, 0, 0}; // Red
  RenderText("Hello World", color, 5, 10, 12); 

/.../

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This solution would have the code constantly reload the .ttf file from disk *and* regenerate the glyph textures every time the developer wanted to call RenderText(). I can't imagine this would be the remotest bit efficient.

Comment: Could not get the above answer to work until i followed your link and read the Mandatory Setup step.glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
 
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

Comment: that link is broken