# Rendering text with SDL2 and OpenGL

Tags: opengl, sdl, sdl-2

I've been trying to have text rendering in my OpenGL scene using SDL2. The tutorial I came across is this one [Rendering text](http://headerphile.blogspot.co.uk/2014/07/sdl2-part-10-text-rendering.html)

I followed the same code, and I get text rendering fine. However the issue I'm having is that there is obviously a "conflict" between the OpenGL rendering and the `SDL_Renderer` used in the code. When I run my scene the text displays but everything else keeps flickering. The following gif shows the issue:

[image]

Any idea on how to overcome this while still just using `SDL2` and `OpenGL`, not another library or anything.

Comment: Maybe this answer could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5289823/1175077

Comment: @jpw I'm using SDL2, so restricted to using SDL_CreateWindow rather than SDL_SetVideoMode

Answer (score 1):

Try render SDL text in texture like:

```
SDL_Texture* renderText(const std::string &message, const std::string &fontFile,
    SDL_Color color, int fontSize, SDL_Renderer *renderer)
{
    //Open the font
    TTF_Font *font = TTF_OpenFont(fontFile.c_str(), fontSize);
    if (font == nullptr){
        logSDLError(std::cout, "TTF_OpenFont");
        return nullptr;
    }   
    //We need to first render to a surface as that's what TTF_RenderText
    //returns, then load that surface into a texture
    SDL_Surface *surf = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, message.c_str(), color);
    if (surf == nullptr){
        TTF_CloseFont(font);
        logSDLError(std::cout, "TTF_RenderText");
        return nullptr;
    }
    SDL_Texture *texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surf);
    if (texture == nullptr){
        logSDLError(std::cout, "CreateTexture");
    }
    //Clean up the surface and font
    SDL_FreeSurface(surf);
    TTF_CloseFont(font);
    return texture;
}
```

See http://www.willusher.io/sdl2%20tutorials/2013/12/18/lesson-6-true-type-fonts-with-sdl_ttf/

Bind SDL_Texture

```
void SDL_BindTexture(SDL_Texture *t)
{
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, t->id);
}
```

And draw using glDrawArrays() like:

```
const GLfloat quadVertices[] = { -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 
    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 
    1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f
}; 

glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, quadVertices);
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
```

Comment: Do I need a shader in this case? Or is there some default thing OpenGL uses.

Comment: For OpenGL - no. OpenGLES - yes.

Comment: Sorry this may not be a good question, but what do I pass to glDrawArrays in this case?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. However this still doesn't show anything. Also I can't access the id variable of SDL_Texture.